# Storing and retrieving functions and their context

Tags: json, caching, local-storage, persistence

I am making an ionic application in which I want to provide the user with offline functionality (i.e manipulate data that is cached).

For example: a user tries to change his profile picture when offline. I am doing this by

1. changing the cached user profile object first
2. then the application tries to update the user profile object in the cloud database.
3. Since there is no internet connection I store the save function, its  context (the class object that it belongs to) and the arguments if any to an object.
4. I store this object into a queue. (I am using this queue to store any other operations that had previously failed to execute due to no internet connection)
5. I have made a "sync service" in my app that subscribes to the "internet OK" event that my "connectivity-service" publishes
6. When my sync service receives the internet OK event it loops through the queue and executes the operations as they should have

When the user closes the application, the data in the queue is lost so I have to store it into memory.The problem here is when I try to store my queue object into cache (indexDB), I get the JSON error due to the circular nature of objects that I ahave in my queue. I am not sure if this is the right practice to persist data for application that have offline functionality support. Am I on the right track ? How can I achieve offline functionality that requires interaction with the database in the cloud with persisting user data once I have internet?

I was thinking of just saving the names of the function (the function to save user) just as a string, and same for the class that contains this function. Then I could add logic to the loop part where I am executing these operations that would call the right function of the right class. This seems like a lot of work as I would need login to know which string maps to which class and which function.

I would have used couch DB and pouch DB but I am far into my project that I would have to start over again.

```
let obj = {
  retry: retry,
  error:error,
  function: f,
  context: context,
  args: args
};

this.syncService.addToJobsQueue(obj);
```

then in my sync service i do something like this :

```
subscribeToConnectivityService(){
console.log("subscribeToConnectivityService");
let me = this;
me.events.subscribe("connectivity-service-event:internet", (val) => {
  console.log("connectivity-service-event:internet : " + val);
  if(val){
    me.completeJobsInQueue();
  }
});}


completeJobsInQueue(){
console.log("completeJobsInQueue");
let me = this;
me.localDBStorage.getJobsQueue().then((response) => {
    if(response==null){response = {}}
    return response;
}).then((jobsQueue) => {
    //clean the jobs queue first
    me.createEmptyJobsQueue();
    for (var key in jobsQueue) {
        me.executeJob(jobsQueue[key]);
    }
}).catch((ex) => {
    console.error('Error getting jobsQueue from localDBStorage: ', ex);
    me.createEmptyJobsQueue();
});}
```

then I execute the functions like this :

```
executeJob(job){
    console.log("executeJob");
    var f = wrapFunction(job.function, job.context, job.args);
    (f)();
}

var wrapFunction = function(fn, context, params) {
    return function() {
        fn.apply(context, params);
    };
}
```

Is there a way to store pointers to the classes and functions that I want to use into cache? or any other technique that I can implement which would not require me to make major changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so after some digging I finally was able to solve this. I did the following steps:

1 - I changed my object being saved in the queue (that will be eventually be stored into cache as JSON), from the object

```
let obj = {
  retry: retry,
  error:error,
  function: f,
  context: context,
  args: args
};
```

I change the function and context object to just have a string value. For my function that would save the user profile object I save its signature "saveUser" and its context class "CloudService" just as string in my like this:

```
obj.context = "saveUser"
obj.context = "CloudService"
```

Then I got rid of the wrapFunction and instead I publish a syncServiceEvent inside my executeJob function as :

```
executeJob(job){
    this.events.publish("syncServiceExecuteJob", job);
}
```

Now in all my services that I expect to provide some sort of offline functionality support I subscribe to the event "syncServiceExecuteJob"

```
events.subscribe("syncServiceExecuteJob", (val) =>{
      let me = this;
      me.syncEventExecuter(val);
});
```

Next I create a sync service event executor just simply validate that the event that the service has received contains the job is meant for it, otherwise ignores it:

```
syncEventExecuter(val){
    console.log("syncServiceExecuteJob");
    console.log(val);
    if(this.constructor.name == val.context){
      this[val.function](val.args);
    }
}
```

The `this[val.function](val.args);` executes the right function with the right arguments array.

I am still not a 100% weather this is the correct way to handle data persistence in an app that supports offline functionality but for now it seems to be working. I am not well educated on this matter and would love advise from the experts here :)